# Returning File Stream with a POST action in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, get

I've always used [HttpGet] for action returning file streams in ASP.NET MVC (with the js window.open) but I need to pass more parameters and I need to use POST: will I get the same behaviour (downloading the file in the browser) in this way ?

Answer (score 0):

> will I get the same behaviour (downloading the file in the browser) in this way ?

That's a definite *maybe*.

A behavior for an http request and response have all sorts of side affects.  For instance, Http Get calls are much more likely to be cached than Http Post calls.  I don't even dare list all of the examples that can be different from a Get to a Post.

That being said, if call you care about is hitting a Url with a Post Body and the response is a streamed file to the browser, then from those specifics, *no* there won't be a difference.  Mainly because the HTTP protocols are pretty specific about the request and response *body* which stays very consistent between most Http Methods.